# How do I filter data with proper algorithm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

So I have that blocks of code:

```
const stops = {
  mainCheckBox : true,
  checkBox: {
    0: true,
    1: true,
    2: true,
    3: true
  }
}

const tickets = [
  {
    segments: [
      {
        stops: ['QWE', 'RTY', 'BGT']
      },
      {
        stops: ['CVB']
      }
    ]
  },
  ... // plus other same objects
]
```

What do I need? I need to filter them according to the length of stops + appropriate checkbox. For example: if I have chekcBox[0] true and legnth of the both stops arrays is 0, then I return the item.

So I wrote that algorithm:

```
const result = tickets.filter(item => {
  if (stops.mainCheckBox) return item
  if (stops.checkBox[0] && item.segments[0].stops.length === 0 && item.segments[1].stops.length === 0) return item
  if (stops.checkBox[1] && item.segments[0].stops.length === 1 && item.segments[1].stops.length === 1) return item
  if (stops.checkBox[2] && item.segments[0].stops.length === 2 && item.segments[1].stops.length === 2) return item
  if (stops.checkBox[3] && item.segments[0].stops.length === 3 && item.segments[1].stops.length === 3) return item
})
```

But that code looks bad and unacceptable. So without other libraries (like lodash and etc), how can I refactor the algorithm?

Comment: btw, filter does not take the return value as result for mapping, it takes a value which reperesents a boolean and this filters the item or not. btw, why is only `item.segments[0]` and `item.segments[1]` intersting? what happens to `item.segments[n]`?

Comment: @Nina Scholz, forget to mention, there are only 2 stops arrays in the segments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array of key/indices and iterate with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
const
    result = tickets.filter(item => 
        stops.mainCheckBox ||
        Object.keys(stops.checkBox).some(i =>
            stops.checkBox[i] &&
            item.segments[0].stops.length === +i &&
            item.segments[1].stops.length === +i
        )
    );
```

Comment: thx for help! I was thinking about `groupBy` function, which makes key of the object as the number of stops, for example: `{0: [items with 0 length of both stops], 1: [items with 1 length of both stops]}`. But not from lodash, any ideas how to group like that?